# Quickbooks API V2 QBD - Looking for example of how to use RecordCountQuery

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am working in .NET, using the QuickBooks V2 API to try and fetch a count of the number of Items the user's QBD.

Does anyone have a working example of how to implement the "RecordCountQuery" class to find the # of Items in QBD?

Here is one of my attempt to do so:

```
//
// Get a record count of the items
//
var qbItemsCount = new RecordCountQuery();

var myResults = qbItemsCount.ExecuteQuery<Item>(_oQBIDataServices.ServiceContext);
```

Error:

```
Intuit.Ipp.Exception.IdsException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message= The RecordCountQuery xml must wrap an existing supported query object. Please modify your query and try again.
  Source=""
  ErrorCode=-2015
```

I gather by this that I should be using an different type in the "ExecuteQuery" method like Intuit.Ipp.Data.QBD.ItemQuery.  I tried this but got a different error.

So what I am asking for is not necessarily correction to the above code, but a WORKING EXAMPLE of the RecordCountQuery class in .NET.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** - Adding .net code

```
RecordCountQuery query = new RecordCountQuery();
CustomerQuery custQuery = new CustomerQuery();
query.Item1 = custQuery;
List<RecordCount> customerRecordCountQuery = query.ExecuteQuery<RecordCount>(context).ToList();
string customerCount = customerRecordCountQuery[0].Count;
```

I hv a working java code. Please check if it is useful.

API endpoint - https://services.intuit.com/sb/recordcount/v2/{*relam_id*}

**POST body**

```
<RecordCountQuery xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
    <CustomerQuery/>
</RecordCountQuery>
```

**Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--XML GENERATED by IntuitDataSyncEngine (IDS) using \\SBDomainServices\CDM\branches\3.9.0-rel-1-->
<RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"
xmlns:xdb          ="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb"
xmlns:xsi          ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation ="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2 ../common/RestDataFilter.xsd"><RecordCounts>
<RecordCount>
<ObjectName>Customer</ObjectName>
<Count>392</Count>
</RecordCount>
</RecordCounts></RestResponse>
```

**Java Code**

```
public int testGetCount() {
    int objectCount = 0;
    try {
        QBCustomerQuery CustomerQuery = QBObjectFactory.getQBObject(
                context, QBCustomerQuery.class);
        QBDRecordCountService iRecordCountSer = QBDServiceFactory
                .getService(context, QBDRecordCountService.class);
        List<QBRecordCountImpl> recordCounts = iRecordCountSer.getCount(
                context, CustomerQuery);
        Iterator<QBRecordCountImpl> iterator = recordCounts.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            QBRecordCountImpl next = iterator.next();
            objectCount = Integer.parseInt(next.getCount().toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Customer count - " + objectCount);
    } catch (QBInvalidContextException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return objectCount;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you Manas.  I am now able to get a record count of my QBD items.

Comment: Glad to know that it was useful :) Please accept the ans.
Thanks

Comment: So how do you do the same thing in v3? I've been struggling with this for quite a while: https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/829658-how-to-select-count-from-invoice-using-idsquery-to-return-int?jump_to=comment_1920684